# iTunes - Sorting issue. Song names that start with 'the' or 'a'

Tags: itunes, sort

[image: Itunes Sorting]

I'm sorry guys if this is an easy fix. But I really couldn't find any useful info about this anywhere. iTunes ignores the 'the' and 'a' in the song names and sorts them this way. as you can see in the screenshot. This makes it extremely hard for me to crosscheck my folders with the iTunes. 
Any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

iTunes will generally import songs with a few different metadata fields. Check out this example where the `name` field is different from the `sort as` field:
[image]

As far as I know, unless these fields are updated for every song in your library, it will sort them as if the `a` or `the` weren't present.